# Compatibility between Particle Photon and Arduino

Tags: wifi

Is it possible to run Arduino on a [Particle Photon](https://store.particle.io/?product=particle-photon)?

I want complete software control over the device so I can connect it to the internet and do stuff without going through Particle's cloud, logins, etc.

Comment: I found several F1 cores, but no F2 cores yet.

Comment: Hi @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I'm very new to this stuff overall. I'm not looking to do any custom electronics (soldering/breadboards/shields) work, just software development. What are these cores and what do they mean in regards to whether I can run Arduino or not?

Comment: A core is a shim between the Arduino libraries and the underlying hardware. Without one you won't be able to use the IDE or any of the Arduino libraries with the board.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OK, so how good/bad is it that you've found 'several' F1 cores but no F2 cores?

Comment: It means that it may be possible to create a F2 core, but that it has not been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new particle dev platform to do this https://www.particle.io/dev